# Trigger works based on type of insert SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am working in SQL Server Management Studio v18, and I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_surface] 
    ON  [dbo].[my_table] 
    FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @surface_m2 REAL
    SET @surface_m2 = (SELECT cast(round(CAST(Dimension1*Dimension2 as decimal)/ cast(1000000 as decimal),3,3) as decimal(10,3)) AS surface FROM my_table WHERE Surface_m2 IS NULL) 
    UPDATE dbo.my_table SET Surface_m2 = @surface_m2
END
```

I have two columns in `my_table`, which are `Dimesion1` and `Dimension2`. I want that the trigger multiplies them, and set the result to other column in the same table, which is `Surface_m2`, whenever this column is null. The trigger does his function, but based on the type of insert I do:

If I insert a row in `my_table` by the graphic environment the trigger works as I wish. With each new row, `Surface_m2` has his own result.

But if I insert by `INSERT INTO` my_table `VALUES ()....` (query) the trigger updates  `Surface_m2` column of all previous rows  with the result of each new insert.

Why is the trigger working like that? Is there any other simple way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you trigger stops working as soon as there are multiple rows in the table. Perhaps the graphical environment is failing to update? A SQL Server trigger that fails to reference `inserted` or `deleted` is almost always broken. But before fixing the trigger, consider whether this data needs to be *stored at all* - if the result is always meant to be computable from other data, storing it just introduces opportunities for *inconsistencies*.

Comment: Triggers are not invoked on a row-by-row basis, they are invoked once only for the whole row set (which might even be zero rows). Triggers need to be written in a set-based fashion by joining on the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` virtual tables so as to perform operations on the new or previous versions of the rows (respectively). Your current trigger is picking an (effectively) random row in the table, calculating based on that row's values, and then overwriting every single row in the table with the newly calculated `@Surface_m2` value.

Comment: Have a read through the [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) and the [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) documentation, although their discussion and demonstration of multiple row-affected triggers is a bit light on.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) & [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Also SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. I assume you are using SQL Server, based on the fact that your title says so.

Comment: Thank you all for your replays. So much work to do with SQL. @Larnu Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Insert trigger gives you actual values that are inserted in a special table called... "inserted".
So what you need to do is join this table against your main table and perform the logic needed, no variables required.
Something like this untested code

```sql
create trigger...
begin

 UPDATE t
 SET Surface_m2 = cast(round(CAST(t.Dimension1*t.Dimension2 as decimal)
  / cast(1000000 as decimal),3,3) as decimal(10,3))
 from dbo.my_table t
 inner join inserted i
   ON i.ID = t.ID
 WHERE t.Surface_m2 IS NULL
    
end
```

This begs the question though, why can't you just insert the Surface_m2 value yourself. Or even better, change Surface_m2 to be a computed column if it's always depends on Dimension1 and Dimension2